# How to disable react-transform-hmr in production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a problem with my create react app. When I run dev version everything is fine. When I'm trying to run build version I get error:

Uncaught Error: locals[0] does not appear to be a `module` object with Hot Module replacement API enabled. You should disable react-transform-hmr in production by using `env` section in Babel configuration. See the example in README: https://github.com/gaearon/react-transform-hmr
    at n (react-datepicker.js:4634)

I tried this: babel.rc file

```
  {
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
     // only enable it when process.env.NODE_ENV is 'development' or undefined
    "development": {
      "plugins": [[
        "react-transform", {
           "transforms": [{
             "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
             // if you use React Native, pass "react-native" instead:
             "imports": ["react"],
             // this is important for Webpack HMR:
             "locals": ["module"]
           }]
           // note: you can put more transforms into array
           // this is just one of them!
        }
      ]]
    }
  }
}
```

and my build command is:

"build": "set NODE_ENV=production && react-scripts build",
Any idea why this happens or where should I look for solutions?
Thanks